# How to add a JLabel to a class which extends JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, extends

as the title says, I would like to add a JLabel to a class (in my case, named GamePanel) which extends JPanel. I tried with

```
    public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener
    {

/*Some of my instructions
*
*/
       public void gamelabel()
       {
             JLabel mylabel = new JLabel();
             mylabel.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 720);
             GamePanel.add(mylabel);    //Here I'm getting an error message
       }

/*Others instructions
*
*/
    }
```

So I really don't know how to do it, but I have the feeling it must be an easy solution... Nevertheless, I couldn't find it.

How could I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the future, whenever you ask a question about a compiler error that you're getting, or about an exception that is being thrown, you'll always want to post the entire error message or exception with your question. This will help clarify your problem for us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `this.add()`  instead of `Gamelabel.add()`.

you can't call `Gamelabel.add()` because to call `Gamelabel.add()` there should be a static method `add()` in `Gamelabel` class but Gamelabel has a inherited instance method `add()` not a static method .

```
   public void Gamelabel() {
        JLabel mylabel = new JLabel();
        mylabel.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 720);
        mylabel.setVisible(true); //unnecessary 
        this.add(mylabel);
    }
```

also use  layout managers .in your code you can't use `setBounds()` method because panel layout is flow (default) .`setbounds` is used for absolute positioning when not using layout managers. so read how to use [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [flow layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) .

also `mylabel.setVisible(true);` is unnecessary because `jlable` is visible by default unlike `jframe`.

Comment: Oh ok I see and understand the mistakes. Thanks a lot, it works!

Comment: @DadoDel and you have to fix the layout problem too. otherwise label not be visible correctly

Comment: @DadoDel Please make sure to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the correct and best answer.